# Error while running a python-Storing Data object in JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've extracted data via api against which I had to transformation to read the data in tabular format. Sample code:

```
import json
import ast
import requests
from pandas import json_normalize
result = requests.get('https://website.com/api')
data = result.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result']['records'])
```

Every time I run above `python(.py)` file in terminal, I get an error in line where it says;

```
in <module>
data = result.json()
```

Also this;

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `print(requests.get('https://website.com/api'))` and see what you get.

Comment: @RaymondKwok, I get this : "<Response [403]>"

Comment: if you further look up for the meaning behind the code 403, you will find it reasonable that `result.json()` may not behave as you expected. For `.json()` to work it gets to be JSON-format text, and if you look at `result.content` it wasn't. I suggest your code to check `result.status_code` and only parse the content with `.json()` if it is a successful code. For which code represents a successful one, you need to read the API's documentation.